# saving nodes created by user on JavaFX GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, save, nodes

enter image description hereI made a GUI on JavaFX that's for creating timetables. when I open the app I can add plans (Buttons) to day columns (VBox). ofc the changes aren't saved after I close the app: the next time I open it the table is empty.
my question is how can I make it save nodes that the user creates so the next time i open the app they're there?

this is the exact part where the nodes get added for what it's worth:

```
void ask_add_plan(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Button b = (Button) event.getSource();
        VBox v = (VBox) b.getParent();

        AnchorPane pop_up = new AnchorPane(); //this pop up is to specify things about the plan 
                                              //but i removed unnecessary code for simplicity
        
        VBox pop_up_v = new VBox();

        Button add = new Button("Add");
      
        add.setOnAction(e->{
            Button plan = new Button(what_to_do.getText());
           
            v.getChildren().add(plan);

            container.getChildren().remove(pop_up); //container is the anchor pane everything's in
        });

       
        pop_up_v.getChildren().add(add);

        pop_up.getChildren().add(pop_up_v);

        container.getChildren().add(pop_up); //container is the anchor pane everything's in
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaFX nodes are just the *presentation* of your data.  They are not meant to be saved.  Store the actual data itself in a private field in your class.

- In your [Application.stop](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#stop()) method, write the data to a file.
- In your [Application.start](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#start(javafx.stage.Stage)) method, read that file and use it to rebuild JavaFX nodes.

```
private static final Path PLANS_FILE =
    Path.of(System.getProperty("user.home"), "plans.txt");

private final List<String> plans = new ArrayList<>();

void ask_add_plan(ActionEvent event) {

    // ...

    add.setOnAction(e -> {
        String planText = what_to_do.getText();

        plans.add(planText);

        Button plan = new Button(planText);
        v.getChildren().add(plan);
        container.getChildren().remove(pop_up);
    });
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
throws Exception {

    // ...

    if (Files.exists(PLANS_FILE)) {
        plans.addAll(Files.readAllLines(PLANS_FILE));

        // Add UI elements for each stored plan.
        for (String planText : plans) {
            Button planButton = new Button(planText);
            v.getChildren().add(planButton);
            container.getChildren().remove(pop_up);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void stop()
throws IOException {
    Files.write(PLANS_FILE, plans);
}
```

The above is just a simplified example.  The file doesn’t have to store just strings.

I get the impression that the data created in the application is more complex than just plan strings.  For complex data, XML may be more a suitable file format.  Or you can use Java serialization.  Or, you can invent your own file format.

You also don’t have to read from and write to a file.  You can use a database, if you’re comfortable with database programming.  Or you can use [Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.prefs/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) (though Preferences are not well suited to storing lists of complex data).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. That still doesn't solve my problem tho. if I was saving simple things like strings and numbers in rows that would've been easy. even in this particular case i might be able to do it with some thinking and SQL tables (I've seen some of them being used while searching for this but i haven't learned them yet). the thing is I'm trying to learn through this and storing data as text or tables doesn't feel like a good option when thinking about more complex structures. here for example the VBox I add to is not the same for every button so I'd have to store that too.

Comment: it just feels that when I go on to more complex structures it would get too complicated if there's no systematic way to do it.

Comment: also if the only solution is to model them using basic data like strings etc. can you please clarify where each of those declarations should go? I use an FXML, controller, css and main files in this project so idk how exactly where each part can be put.

Comment: I figured there was a parent data object to which the plans belonged.  But you haven’t shown us any of that, so I can only answer based on what you have shown.  Writing to a plain text file is the simplest solution, but if your problem is more complex, it will require a more complex solution.  I’m afraid there is no way around that.  If nothing else, I hope this answer illustrates that the VBox and Buttons are not the things you want to store;  their underlying data (that is, the model) is.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer VGR ig i was looking for a quick solution when one didn't exist. thanks a lot for elucidating that and for including that code all is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should use MVP (model-view-presenter) pattern. Saving data in UI layer is not a good practice. Create a model with data and then serialize it.

Comment: ig there isn't an easier way to it then? I thought there might be a way to edit the source file everytime the user adds or removes sth like for example edit the FXML. if not then i'll just have to do what you said.